# translate layer cake representation in German

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Whats the name of the ***layer cake representation*** in german?
I know that it is not "Kuchenschichten Darstellung"

Comment: Why do you want it in German?

Comment: Schichtkuchendarstellung?

Comment: @Ed_4434: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this PDF](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~kuettler/lehre/ana3_ws11/ana3-uebungen.pdf) of exercises in measure and integration in several variables the term *Schichttorten-Satz* is used in Übungsblatt $11$ for the layer cake theorem (and indeed *layer cake theorem* is explicitly given as an English gloss for the term). Another PDF simply used the English term.