# The translation in french of «Layer Cake Representation»

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, translation-request, mathematical-french

I would like to know if there exists a generic way of referring to this identity $$\int_X |f(x)| \mathrm{d} \mu(x) = \int_0^\infty \mu\{x \in X : |f(x)| > t \} \mathrm{d} t$$ in french. In english, it is the layer cake representation. The same question arose on this site for the German translation : [translate layer cake representation in German](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849164/translate-layer-cake-representation-in-german) and the question was closed ; I apologize if it is not on-topic.

I didn't managed to find to wikipedia page in french : see [EN] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation.

Comment: Maybe the more or less equivalent probability statement $EX = \int P(X\geq x)\,dx$ has already a French denomination...

Comment: Do you know the name of this identity in english ? I would then add it to the question for referncing. Also, I think I already saw something like *représentation en millefeuille*. Is this possible ?

Comment: Indeed, it's proposed and discussed [here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?14,1337694). Why not, it's a nice term... Besides, no idea of a name in english for the probabilistic formula.

Comment: The term "layer cake representation" is used in geology and in hydrology, so one might look to see if French geologists have already come up with an answer.